# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL

Tags: javascript, console, embed, vimeo

I've incorporated Vimeo into a WordPress theme I'm building, and I get these errors:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://themes.ibrogram.com/beta/blog/ from frame with URL
>   http://player.vimeo.com/video/4749536. Domains, protocols and ports
>   must match.

---

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://themes.ibrogram.com/beta/blog/ from frame with URL
>   http://player.vimeo.com/video/28496744?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match.

It also (I think) is the reason for the page *still loading*: http://themes.ibrogram.com/beta/blog/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324108/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url

Comment: It's working fine for me, page loads fine, video plays fine. No console errors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read something about Javascript access security here:

- http://javascript.about.com/od/reference/a/frame3.htm
- [Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame warning in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858811/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-warning-in-safari)
- ["Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL..." error being continuously generated in Chrome webkit inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010170/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url-error-being-continuously)
- http://blog.chromium.org/2008/12/security-in-depth-local-web-pages.html

---

Specifically about implementing Vimeo and JavaScript unsafe access, I found this on a [discussion on the Vimeo forums](http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:28492):

> If you're using a webkit browser (Safari or Chrome) that error is
>   actually coming from the Webkit Inspector trying to access the iframe
>   (the Webkit Inspector is actually written in HTML and Javascript).
>
> The
>   thing to make sure is that you can't call any of the api or addEvent
>   methods on the iframe until the player has finished loading. As per
>   the example, you need to add the "onLoad" event first and then execute
>   your code inside of that handler.

---

And second, I checked link you provided, and it loads fast and fine to me, so it is definitely not reason why you keep having this page loading long time

Comment: The initial page loading time is fine, I'm refering to this: http://d.pr/noOV - something is going on here and it only happens when vimeo is on the page.

Comment: I see javascript unsafe error in console, but either on page with Vimeo video object, it loads just fine here

Comment: no, I'm using chrome, and checked in FF and Safari too, no problems at all