# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame errors with vimeo

Tags: javascript, jquery, protocols, vimeo

Site was working last time I checked but it now seems many of the JS aspects are broken.  Tweets have vanished and the jQuery colorbox no longer works?

http://www.jamesperrett.co.uk/

Get the following console errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( www.jamesperrett.co.uk:178
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' jquery.validationEngine.js:28

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL [site] from frame with URL [vimeo]. 
Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Last one repeats for every video.

Worrying if this is something to do with Vimeo, possibly secure content? The site is not `https`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438020/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url)

Comment: The Vimeo erros are explained in the possible duplicate link above. About the others, it's hard to tell without seeing the code. Mauybe you should post them as separate questions, along with the related code snippets.

Comment: The problem with the question posted as a duplicate is that no one could actually see his errors, it was working fine for others. So it's quite a different question.

Comment: I just edited the accepted answer there with something that probably fits your case (I was going to post it here, but as I consider it a duplicate, I posted there). Quote: *If you're using a webkit browser (Safari or Chrome) that error is actually coming from the Webkit Inspector trying to access the iframe (the Webkit Inspector is actually written in HTML and Javascript).*

Comment: So how do I stop the webkit inspector creating these errors? Sorry I don't really understand the solution.

Comment: I guess you should just ignore them (I mean the Vimeo errors; the other ones are caused by something else)

Comment: Well I can't ignore them, as they're breaking the site. This occurs in IE too so not just Safari or Chrome issue.

Comment: As I said, I believe it's the other two errors that are breaking your site, not the vimeo/iframe error.

Answer (score 0):

For the live error, your are referencing jquery with latest version (1.9.1)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

This version of jquery no more support `live()`, it is replaced by `.on()` using delegation. So the plugin `jquery.validationEngine.js` no more works correctly.

Solution could be to update to a new version of the validation plugin (if available) or to modify source code of this plugin or to downgrade to older jquery version which still support live.